# Remove elements from an array matching patterns from a file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to build a function that:

- Gets arguments and assigns them to an array.
- Removes all the elements that match the **Exclude file**.

Exclude file is a text file that contains a list of strings to exclude separated by lines.

For example:

The **Exclude file** is: `list.txt`.
It contains:

> value1
>
> value2

Let's assume we call the function with these arguments:

```
Function value1 value2 value3
```

The desired output would be:

> value3

So far I tried to iterate through the `list.txt` and overwrite the array with array minus the String from the file. But it seems that it doesn't overwrite the array and instead it appends the values.

The output I get right now is:

> value3 value2 value3

My code is:

```
function Function {
    argsArr=( "$@" )
    while read p; do
        argsArr="${argsArr[@]//$p*/}"
    done <list.txt
    echo "${argsArr[@]}"
}
```

Comment: Your code is correct only change is replace ""(double quotes) in line 4 with braces(). It should work i have tested and found it working. Remove extra slash before $p in 4th line.

Comment: @Koushik Thank you too, you can post this as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple grep check would suffice:

```
$ cat list.txt 
value1
value2
$ function Function
> {
> for i in "$@"
> do
> fgrep -q "$i" list.txt || echo "$i"
> done
> }
$ Function value1 value2 value3
value3
$
```

We just iterate through the parameters passed to function and grep for that parameter in `list.txt`(Exclude file), if exit code is non-0 i.e not present we then just print it out.

If you want the result in array, declare it at start of function using `array=()`, just append the parameter to an array like this: `fgrep -q "$i" list.txt || array+=("$i")` and at the end of function just do `echo ${array[@]}`

Edit 1: just using an array

```
$ function Function
> {
> declare -a array=()
> for i in "$@"
> do
> fgrep -q "$i" list.txt || array+=("$i")
> done
> echo "${array[@]}"
> }
$ Function value1 value2 value3
value3
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out line 4:

```
function Function {

    argsArr=( "$@" )
    while read p; do
        argsArr=(${argsArr[@]/$p*/})
    done <list.txt
    echo "${argsArr[@]}"
}
```